# PrimeFaces lightBox opens too slow

Tags: jsf, primefaces

It seems that PrimeFaces lightBox opens images too slow even if images hosted localy. I looked over documentation for `p:lightbox` but seems there is no option to adjust the speed of opening lightBox window. Is there a way how to fix it?

Comment: Hi, please read [tour], including [ask] and [mcve] and improve your question. And what is 'slow'? Loading 10.000 images in 2 minutes? Or 10 in 20 seconds (still if it is 40MB each)...

Comment: @Kukeltje well, if it seems that the question is incomplete... maybe.. I just meaned slow open the lightbox window. For example there are many solutions in jquery for lightboxes but primefaces lightbox at first open the black window and after that tries to show image inside it and the whole process seems like it would be great to increase speed of the whole process... and it's just one image. that's all. you could try to play with primefaces lightbox demo and the whole expirience is the same - I mean it very like I use it localy.

Comment: check the source for animations and override them... https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/blob/master/src/main/resources/META-INF/resources/primefaces/lightbox/lightbox.js